# How to get perfect launch in NFS:MW?

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005

Sometimes, I get a perfect launch, and sometimes I do not.

[image]

How should I accelerate to get the "Perfect Launch"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the moment of race start the pointer of the rev counter must be blue. Just give some power before starting to see where the pointer turns blue to get a feel of how much power you must give.

The blue zone changes from car to car, afaik, so you'll need to adapt.

Comment: The pointer isn't blue in the screenshot because the pointer only turns blue before the race starts.

Answer (score 2):

Just accelerate the car and leave acceleration when the second countdown reaches to mid-point of your screen, and then accelerate twice...

You'll then make a prefect launch...

Answer (score 1):

During the countdown, between the numbers "2" and "1", give acceleration to the car to get perfect launch.

Answer (score 1):

When you accelerate, the pointer in the nitrous bar moves. If you release the acceleration the pointer comes back to its first (middle) position. You need to make the pointer come back to the middle position, just before the end of the countdown and at the same time you have to accelerate again.

Answer (score 1):

*The pointer must turn blue (or a different colour if you use custom gauges).*
Then, **press accelerate until the Start Race Timer reaches 1, and then let the pointer go down to the middle of the gauge, where it becomes blue.** The result is a Perfect Launch!
Note that this may not be available for all cars, as they may have different RMPs required for Perfect Launch; the example provided is for Porsche Carrera GT.